# Is there any advantage to using a callback function here (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback, arguments

For some reason, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around callback functions in JS. I think it finally clicked on how to use them (sorta) but I still can't figure out why I'd need to. How are these two pieces of code different and why would using the callback version be better? They both do the same thing. They both eliminate the need for duplicate code. They're about the same file size. It's not obvious to me why I'd use the callback example over the first - at least if the objective is to prevent duplicate code (that's what I read as the reason for using a callback like this).

Version 1

```
    // no need to pass a function -- not a callback
    function addNumsAndMultiply(num1, num2) {
        findSum(num1, num2);
        var product = num1 * num2;
        alert("The product of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is: " + product);
    }

    function addNumsAndDivide(num1, num2) {
        findSum(num1, num2);
        var quotient = num1 / num2;
        alert("The quotient of " + num1 + "/" + num2 + " is: " + quotient);
    }

    function findSum(num1, num2) {
        var sum = num1 + num2;
        alert("The sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is: " + sum);
    }

    addNumsAndMultiply(3,4);
    addNumsAndDivide(30,5);
```

Version 2

```
    // passed the function -- this is a callback
    function addNumsAndWhat(num1, num2, callback) {
        var sum = num1 + num2;
        alert("The sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is: " + sum);
        callback(num1,num2);
    }

    function multiply(num1, num2) {
        var product = num1 * num2;
        alert("The product of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is: " + product);
    }

    function divide(num1, num2) {
        var quotient = num1 / num2;
        alert("The quotient of " + num1 + "/" + num2 + " is: " + quotient);
    }

    addNumsAndWhat(3,4,multiply);
    addNumsAndWhat(30,5,divide);
```

Comment: The callback is not useful here, but it is useful if `addNumsAndWhat` does a bunch of stuff asynchronously (e.g., talks to a Web server). When the Web server responds, `addNumsAndWhat` can then use the callback to tell it "Sorry it took so long, but here's the answer to your question."

Comment: I partially disagree with Raymond. A callback function is not only useful when dealing with asynchronous tasks, it is also the easiest way to implement the strategized design pattern. It's a way to eliminate code duplication.

Comment: @RaymondChen While callbacks are primarily used to handle async, that's not its *only* use.

Comment: I'm not saying that async is the **only** use for callbacks; I was just giving an example of how callbacks could become useful in the context of something that does a calculation and produces a single result. But I think we all agree that in this case, the callback is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main benefit in your scenario of using a callback function is for abstraction and modularity.

The function:

```
addNumsAndWhat();
```

Allows for you to give it two numbers, add them, and then use the callback function to manipulate them in some way, where as the functions:

```
addNumsAndMultiply();
addNumsAndDivide();
```

are very specific in what they do.

To summarize, there isn't any real benefit to using a callback the way you currently are unless you care about the small bonus modularity with using that callback.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the callbacks right but it doesn't really make sense where you're using them.

The biggest bang for the buck in Javascript callbacks is in async operations - making a network call, for example. Here's some sample code:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

It's very simple - you're kicking off the call and giving it a function to call when it's done. No need to poll or do any other synchro-stuff, you just wait to be notified when it's done, failed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is one minor benefit to using the callback method, though in *this* use-use it may be overkill:

/ passed the function -- this is a callback
    function addNumsAndWhat(num1, num2, callback) {
        var sum = num1 + num2;
        alert("The sum of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is: " + sum);
        callback(num1,num2);
    }

```
function multiply(num1, num2) {
    var product = num1 * num2;
    alert("The product of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is: " + product);
}

function divide(num1, num2) {
    var quotient = num1 / num2;
    alert("The quotient of " + num1 + "/" + num2 + " is: " + quotient);
}

addNumsAndWhat(3,4,multiply);
addNumsAndWhat(30,5,divide);
```

You could say something like:

```
task = {
  multiply: multiply,
  divide: divide
};

addNumsAndWhat(4, 5, task['divide']);
```

Thus allowing a string argument to be passed, perhaps from a configuration object or a business/game rule engine.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples you provided, using callback doesn't really shine in its usefulness. In fact, even though you call function passed as a parameter "callback" it really doesn't make it feel as such. A true callback function is typically the one when the caller needs to know the result of some function, which may or may not be an asynchronous operation.

[Js Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bju76y8s/2/)

Code:

```
// Asynchronous operation to fetch json
function fetchJSON(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // When the work is done, we notify the caller
    cb({ name: "maunovaha", age: 29 }, null); 
  }, 1000);
}

// Asynchronous call
fetchJSON(function(data, error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error occurred while fetching JSON: " + error);
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the data
  console.log(data);
});
```

So in short, the above example uses a similar format of node.js data/error processing. The callback could return also the error instead of data and it would be displayed accordingly. Hopefully this helps.